# Set ItemsPanelTemplate to dynamically created ListBox in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, listbox

I have a `ListBox` control in WP8

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <toolkit:WrapPanel Height="120" Width="410" Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBoxItem Margin="0,0,20,0" Width="120" Height="120" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
        ListBoxItem 1
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem Margin="0,0,20,0" Width="120" Height="120" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
        ListBoxItem 2
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem Margin="0,0,10,0" Width="120" Height="120" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
        ListBoxItem 3
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

Now I have to add this `ListBox` at runtime. I can manage to add `ListBoxItems` but not able to set the `ItemsPanelTemplate`. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ListBox lb = new ListBox();
ItemsPanelTemplate ddd = new ItemsPanelTemplate();
lb.ItemTemplate = ddd;
```

Everything in xaml is classes. Remember it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how to add that WrapPanel in ddd?

Comment: There is different way - [use this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/6227660f-7aa1-41c4-9acb-ec3cb45365bb/how-to-set-itemspanelitemspaneltemplate-in-metro-c?forum=winappswithcsharp).